# Add to join table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, join

So I have four database tables.

Users (:name etc..) Recipes (:name, :description, :user_id etc..), Scrapbooks (:name, :description, :user_id) and Scrapbook_Entry (:user_id, recipe_id, :scrapbook_id)

I am able to populate the Users, Recipes and Scrapbooks tables fine but what I now want to do is have an option to save a recipe into a scrapbook. By doing this I need to populate the Scrapbook_Entry table which I have made a model for.

Scrapbook_Entry Model:

```
has_one :recipe
has_one :scrapbook
```

Recipe Model:

```
has_many :scrapbooks, through: :scrapbook_entries
```

Scrapbook Model

```
has_many :recipes, through: :scrapbook_entries
```

User Model

```
has_many :recipes, dependent: :destroy
has_many :scrapbooks, dependent: :destroy
```

I want to create a form in the Recipe view to allow me to select a scrapbook to save the recipe into and for it then to submit and populate the Scrapbook_Entry table.

**My question is:** Will I need to create a new controller for my scrapbook_entries and have a create method in that or would I be able to use the recipes controller and if so, how so?

I am new to rails so still trying to figure it all out. Thank you!

Comment: You didn't really tell us WHAT it is you are having issues with. Only what you have and what you want to do.

Comment: Apologies! Is that a bit more specific? Added an edit.

Answer (score 0):

You will not need a new controller for this. You should be able to do something along the lines of

```
@recipe.scrapbook_entries.build(scrapbook: @scrapbook)
```

assuming you have a `@recipe` variable with a `Recipe` object in it, and a `@scrapbook` variable with a `Scrapbook` object in it.

Comment: would this be put within the recipes controller in the create method?

Comment: If you are linking a recipe as soon as it is created, yes. However, it does not necessarily have to.

Comment: Ahh yes. Apologies. The Recipe and Scrapbook would have already been created. Thats why I am struggling. Trying to figure out how to set up the form and then where to direct it to. Im guessing the recipes controller but not sure under what method

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

The way it works is that it takes a "nested model" (in your case, `ScrapBookEntry`), and allows you to send data directly to it from the parent model (`Recipe`). It's got a learning curve, but comes in very useful especially when you start dealing with lots of modular data

---

**Accepts Nested Attributes For**

There's a [great RailsCast on this subject here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

[image]

It works by building an ActiveRecord object for your nested model through your parent model's controller, thus allowing Rails to populate both objects when the form is submitted. This means you can add as much data as you want to your nested model whilst keeping your code efficient

---

**Your Code**

Instead of creating a new controller, you should be able to handle all the processing in your `Recipes` controller, like this:

```
#app/models/recipe.rb
Class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :scrapbook_entries
end

#app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb
def new
    @recipe = Recipe.new
    @recipe.scrapbook_entries.build #-> repeat for number of fields you want
end

def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
    @recipe.save
end

private
def recipe_params
    params.require(:recipe).permit(:recipe, :params, scrapbook_entries_attributes: [:extra, :data, :you, :want, :to, :save])
end

#app/views/recipes/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @recipe do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :example_field %>
    <%= f.fields_for :scrapbook_entries do |s| %>
         <%= f.text_field :extra_data %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for all this information Rich. Will this still work the same if the recipe and scrapbook data already exists and I just want to use the form to populate the Scrapbook_entry table with the existing data?

Comment: Sure - we use something similar. We have a newsletter app where you can create a new message & add subscribers. The subs _have_ to exist already, and we just use a `select` form element to pick them

Comment: This works well because the way I've suggested only sends data to the join model. We had a really hard time working out how to create new elements _through_ a join model, and turns out if you want that to work, you've got to embed another `accepts_nested_attributes_for` inside the join

Comment: You're basically just populating the model with `ids`. Your validation is going to be front-end, but either way, you're just going to send that model an `id` for recipe & `id` for scrapbook ;)